How to Dynamically Display Blog Posts Related to Custom Post Types in WordPress with ACF and Elementor Pro
I'm working on a WordPress website using Elementor Pro and Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) for a sports club that offers multiple sports activities. I've created a template that reflects the structure of an individual sports offer page - for example, the title of the sport, a description, and an image. So far, so good, and this part is working as expected.
However, I also want to display news/blog posts related to each specific sport offer on its respective page. For instance, when I am on the Badminton page, I want to show blog posts related to Badminton. When I am on the Basketball page, I want to show blog posts related to Basketball.
Here's what I've done so far:

Defined blog categories as taxonomies in ACF. (Field types for spot offer)Basketball) as a category.

Linked these categories to the respective sport offer pages.

Assigned the corresponding categories to the blog posts. The problem is that when I try to display the blog posts, all posts are shown, regardless of the category. I can't seem to make the posts dynamically reflect the current sport offer. ACF dynamic key

edited function.php, but it didn't work (here my taxonomy was named cat, I changed it to category now) :


// functions.php
function filter_posts_by_custom_field($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_singular('sportabteilungen')) {
        $term_id = get_field('blog_kategorie');
        if ($term_id) {
            $query->set('cat', $term_id);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_by_custom_field');

Do I even need to edit the function.php? What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I ensure that only the relevant blog posts for each sport offer are displayed?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Could you please try to check what value your are getting in $term_id = get_field('blog_kategorie'); by adding var_dump($term_id); die(); please try to do this on develop or localhost because it might be not working because of we are not getting value from $term_id.

Hey you could use a different approach in the form of a tax_query
function filter_posts_by_custom_field($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_singular('sportabteilungen')) {
        $term_id = get_field('blog_kategorie');
        if ($term_id) {
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category', // replace 'category' with your custom taxonomy if it's not the default category
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $term_id
                )
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_by_custom_field');

